# apt-get upgrade not installing upgrades through crontab job

Tags: apt, cron, upgrade

After checking on how to make updates automatic with crontab, I've edited mine, as root, adding the following line:

```
00 11 * * * /usr/bin/apt-get upgrade -q -y >> /var/log/apt-upgrade.log
```

Now, if I manually run apt-get upgrade some minutes later, it'll show that it didn't install any of the upgrades.
The log does not report any errors at all, nor warnings. It's just a common list

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following packages will be upgraded:
  binutils fontconfig fontconfig-config gnupg gpgv libcurl3
  libcurl4-openssl-dev libfontconfig1 libgcrypt11 libgcrypt11-dev libgd2-xpm
  libidn11 libidn11-dev libperl5.14 libpq5 libsqlite3-0 libssl-dev libssl-doc
  libssl1.0.0 libtiff4 linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64 linux-libc-dev openjdk-7-jre
  openjdk-7-jre-headless openssh-client openssh-server openssl perl perl-base
  perl-modules ssh
31 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/93.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 613 kB of additional disk space will be used.
```

Other things I've also tried (not all at the same time, obviously), with no results:

```
00 11 * * * apt-get upgrade -q -y >> /var/log/apt-upgrade.log
00 11 * * * root /usr/bin/apt-get upgrade -q -y >> /var/log/apt-upgrade.log
00 11 * * * apt-get upgrade -y >> /var/log/apt-upgrade.log
```

And nothing happens, no upgrades actually get installed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried redirecting even the STDERR to a file ? Just use `<command> &> /var/log/apt-upgrade_both.log`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive`. I seem to recall it was a bit tricky to find, since it's actually an option for `debconf`, not `apt-get`. However, it's mentioned e.g. [here](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.automatic-upgrades.html), and of course in the manual of [`debconf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man7/debconf.7.html).

So, make a script that contains

```
#/bin/sh
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get upgrade -q -y
```

and run that from cron. And remember to run `apt-get update` too.

Of course perhaps you should be using [`unattended-upgrades`](https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades) or something that's especially designed for this.

But I have one Debian machine using this script, and it works ok:

```
#/bin/sh
apt-get -q -q  update 
if apt-get -s upgrade | grep -q "0 upgraded" ; then
        true
else
        DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y -q upgrade
fi
```

The first `apt-get -s` is there to suppress the output and useless email in case there's nothing to upgrade.

Similar [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/556385/how-can-i-install-apt-packages-non-interactively) on askubuntu.

Comment: That didn't work. Called the script from crontab `00 16 * * * /usr/share/apt-uu.sh` , waited a bit, ran apt-get upgrade manually and the list was still there, no upgrade happened.

Comment: @Arthur, just to double-check, does the script run correctly? You've set in in root's `crontab` and the script has execute permissions? Also, I can't remember what happens without setting `DEBIAN_FRONTEND`, but I think `apt-get` should run partially, so you should be getting _some_ output in the email that cron sends.