# cronjob does not output message for automated apt

Tags: linux, apt, cron

I am new to linux and I am trying to automate my update/upgrade script for my raspberry pi.
Right now it is set to do it every 1 minute, so I can see whether it logs what it does. Later on I will be making it so that it would run once every X time. However it does not log anything nor does it create the out.log file.

The steps I take:

```
crontab -e
#I used the following line
01 * * * * root apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y > /home/cronbin/out.log
```

I then save it:

```
CTRL + X
Y
ENTER
```

I did read about unattended upgrades and this post ([apt-get upgrade not installing upgrades through crontab job](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/314769/apt-get-upgrade-not-installing-upgrades-through-crontab-job)) was also an interesting read, however I am trying to learn/work with linux and therefore decided to still ask this question in the hopes of finding out what I am doing wrong and how to make it work.

Comment: You need to add this to root's crontab, not your own.

Comment: Your crontab entry should go to `/etc/crontab` as it contains the user column.

Comment: @ajgringo619 I'm in the root's crontab if I enter in through ~, am I not?

Comment: @annahri so the output log should go to /etc/crontab rather then my own dir?

Comment: I like @annahri's solution better, but to use root's crontab you need to run `sudo crontab -e` to edit it.

Comment: No one pointed this out, but the sixth column in your cron job (“root”) is not necessary and in fact wrong when using “crontab -e”.

Comment: You only need the user in the sixth column in /etc/crontab (and /etc/cron.d/ files). When using a user’s crontab (even the root user) the user is implied.

Comment: to clarify: to run every minute you need `* * * * *`, the above `1 * * * *` runs ever hour at minute 1, so 8:01AM, 9:01AM.. etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apt` generally requires root permissions, and so you should put this in the `root crontab` instead of a `user crontab`. On RPi, you can actually get away with using `sudo` in a `user crontab` as long as the user is **pi**, but this may not work on many other distributions - it's not a good practice.

Instead, use this:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

This will open the `root crontab` for editing, and you can enter something like this which will run `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` once per day at 12:00 noon, and write all of the results to the file `/home/pi/upgrade_results.log`:

```
* 12 * * * apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade >> /home/pi/upgrade_results.log 2>&1
```

- Please review `man apt-get` to get the latest information for your system, and all of the important details re use of this command.
- No `-y` option is needed for `update` as it does not generally prompt the user.
- The `>>` redirect **appends** output to the log file; if you want only the results of the most recent run, replace the **append** redirect with the **overwrite** redirect: `>`
- The `2>&1` redirect combines the normal `stdout` (`1`) output with any `stderr` (`2`) error messages; this is the same output you would get in your terminal if you ran these commands from the command line of your interactive shell.
- see the [crontab guru](https://crontab.guru/#0_12_*_*_4) for help structuring your schedule.

When you test this `cron` job, you should not run it at 1 minute intervals because that ***may not*** be sufficient time to run both commands to completion. IOW, you're running these commands *"on top of each other"* with potentially harmful effect. If you feel the need to run this repeatedly for testing purposes, you should run the commands "manually" first, and then use the `-s` or `--dry-run` option in your `cron` job. Once you are satisfied the `cron` job is working, be sure to remove the `-s` or `--dry-run` option from the `apt-get` command.

`upgrade` can generate a fair amount of output, and if you use the **append** redirect `>>`, your log file will become large over time. You should review it regularly, and either trim or simply delete the file. If you want to constrain the size of your log *automatically*, consider the `logrotate` command, or perhaps another `cron` job that pipes the log file through `tail` with the `-c` option to a temporary location & overwrites the log file with the *tmp* file.

Comment: may I ask what I was doing wrong, that your code did work and mine didn't? Wasn't I giving root permission? (I thought the "root" command stood for that?)

Comment: @ItrysohardbutIcryharder: AFAIK, there is no command called `root`. `root` refers to the user `root` - it's not a *command*. `root` is a.k.a. the "super user" - the user with the highest privileges on the system. Most Unix & Linux systems today use `sudo` to grant elevated privileges to 'regular' users. On the Raspberry Pi, the user `pi` is effectively the default `root` user; this because `pi` has been delegated `ALL` root privileges with no requirement to submit a password to use those privileges. There are good `man` pages on your system that explain `sudo`.

Comment: ah, thanks for clarifying! Appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

You can run the upgrade in a subshell in `crontab -e`via the `root` user !Important

like so:

```
1 * * * * (/usr/bin/apt-get update;/usr/bin/apt-get dist-upgrade -y) >> /home/cronbin/out.log 2>&1
```

`2>&1` will forward any errors to the output

which outout will append to /home/cronbin/out.log (although I think `/var/log/cron.log` is more appropriate place for the log)

---

also in `crontab -e` you do not specify the `user` after the time:

```
01 * * * * root
           ^^^^
```

you specify the user only in scripts that are within `/etc/cron.*/` folders

Comment: Construction `2>&1  >> /home/cronbin/out.log` do not do what you want. `>> /home/cronbin/out.log 2>&1` do it

Comment: good catch. I updated my answer

Comment: Don't write to `/var/log/cron.log` directly. Either use the logging subsystem (see `man logger` and the `logger` command) or write to your own file in `/var/log`.

Comment: I was just saying that that place is more appropriate. Of course the file can be called something custom..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use command `crontab -e` to edit your `cron` record you should use line like this:

```
1 * * * * apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y > /home/cronbin/out.log
```

When you use private `cron` record you should not add the username (root)
P.S. And will be better to append the output to the log file instead of recreate it every time. Replace this:

```
> /home/cronbin/out.log
```

with this:

```
>> /home/cronbin/out.log
```

And also it is not wise to run it every minute because execution of update can take longer. And you will have two (or more) `apt` processes. Reasonable is to run update/upgrade once per 24 hours.